# how to pass the value in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I need to pass the new value from _identifier to GetUID.identifier2 in **GetUID class**, so I can take the identifier2 and encrypt that. pls help me :(. this is my code:

## GetUID

```
class GetUID extends StatefulWidget {
  static var identifier2 = '';
  // static var identifier2 = 'wakwaw';
  const GetUID({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _GetUIDState createState() => _GetUIDState();
}

class _GetUIDState extends State<GetUID> {
  static String _identifier = 'Unknown';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initUniqueIdentifierState();
  }

  Future<void> initUniqueIdentifierState() async {
    String identifier;
    GetUID.identifier2 = _identifier;
    try {
      identifier = (await UniqueIdentifier.serial)!;
    } on PlatformException {
      identifier = 'Failed to get Unique Identifier';
    }
    if (!mounted) return;
    setState(() {
      _identifier = identifier;
    });
    GetUID.identifier2 = _identifier;
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      'Your Unique Identifier : $_identifier\n',
    );
  }
}
```

In GetUID class, I generate new unique identifier for device, then I put that in _identifier, and in ecrypt class, I take the _identifier value and convert that to MD5; No problem with that, the only problem I got is when I took _identifier value, it takes wrong value :(

## Encrypt

```
class EncryptImei extends StatefulWidget {
  const EncryptImei({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EncryptImeiState createState() => _EncryptImeiState();
}

class _EncryptImeiState extends State<EncryptImei> {
  String _encrypted = '';
  var nilai = GetUID.identifier2;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initEncrypImeiState();
  }

  Future<void> initEncrypImeiState() async {
    String encrypted;
    var bytes = utf8.encode(GetUID.identifier2);
    var md = md5.convert(bytes);
    try {
      encrypted = (md.toString());
    } on PlatformException {
      encrypted = 'Failed to Encrypt IMEI';
    }
    if (!mounted) return;
    setState(() {
      _encrypted = encrypted;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      'Your Encrypted Imei : $_encrypted',
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that I have understood your question, because It wasn't so clear, I think that you shouldn't use StatefulWidget for that scope but a simple class since as far as I see you are using it only to generate your identifier.

Something like this should be enough

```
class GetUid {
  String identifier;

  GetUid(this.identifier);

  Future getUniqueIdentifier() async {
    // do your stuff
    return this.identifier;
  }
}
```

You initialize you value if you need to then you call getUniqueIdentifier or you can use static before the getUnitqueIdentifier if you don't have any need to initialize or create istances.